# Problem with Icinga web installation - server side errors

Tags: nagios, network-monitoring, icinga

I have successfully installed and configured [Icinga 1.3](http://www.icinga.org/) and got the basic
web interface up and running and all is good.

I'm now trying to get icinga-web to work. I've followed the instructions
documented here:

> http://docs.icinga.org/latest/en/icinga-web-scratch.html

When I browse to the icinga-web app I am able to logon but get a blank page. When I
do a view-source I see all the HTML and markup for the page and also the
following error in Chrome's developer tools:

`GET http://nagios.node/icinga-web/appkit/squishloader/javascript 500
(Internal Server Error)`

Upon checking `/usr/local/icinga-web/app/data/log/icinga-web-2011-03-16.log` I
am seeing this identical error for every request I make of the page:

```
[Wed Mar 16 01:29:08 2011] [fatal] Uncaught AppKitPHPError: PHP Error
mkdir() [function.mkdir]: File exists
(/usr/local/icinga-web/app/cache/config/compile.xml_development__033d402eaeb08f42e4e3d5f8474e444805e2c7c6.php:1327)
(/usr/local/icinga-web/app/modules/AppKit/lib/logging/AppKitExceptionHandler.class.php:20)`
```

As per the install docs I tried clearing the cache with:

`rm /usr/local/icinga-web/app/cache/config/*.php`

And then restarting apache but I can't seem to get past this.

I built icinga-web today from the git repo at:

`git://git.icinga.org/icinga-web.git`

I also tried building from the 1.3.0 tar ball as well but still get the same problem.

Has anyone encountered this issue before?

**Update:**

This is installed on:

- Centos 5.2 32 bit x86
- Apache 2.2.3 (standard repo install)
- PHP 5.2.17 (installed from IUS Community Packages)
- MySQL 5.0 (standard repo install)
- IDOUtils installed - I used this quick start: http://docs.icinga.org/latest/en/quickstart-idoutils.html

Comment: What operating system are you using? Did you install the IDOUtils?

Comment: @kenny.r - sorry, copy and paste fail, I've added an update to the question. IDOUtils is installed.

Comment: @kenny - problem solved. See my answer. I think it's one of those PHP oddities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I poked about with this and the problem seems to be within the Agavi components, specifically:

> `lib/agavi/src/filter/AgaviExecutionFilter.class.php`

And within the `writeCache()` method:

```
@mkdir(AgaviConfig::get('core.cache_dir') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 
        self::CACHE_SUBDIR .
        DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR , 
        array_slice($groups, 0, -1)), 0777, true);
```

I dropped a logger line into this code and saw that mkdir is trying to recursively create a directory such as:

> `/usr/local/icinga-www/app/cache/content/amF2YXNjcmlwdF9jb250ZW50/QXBwS2l0X1dpZGdldHMvU3F1aXNoTG9hZGVy`

I deleted this, restarted apache but the problem persisted.

At this point the server was running PHP 5.2.17.

I upgraded PHP to 5.3.5 and this issue magically resolved itself.

Out of interest I knocked PHP back to 5.2.17 to see if there were any differences between the `mkdir()` function behavior in that version compared to the one in 5.3.5. A test script showed that all that PHP did was warn that the folder existed in both versions, there was no hard error thrown.

Also, and bizarrely, icinga-web started working with PHP 5.2.17....and I have no idea why. I checked both version's php.ini files thinking that the error_reporting settings may have changed, but they were the same (except that PHP 5.3.5 is set to `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE | E_DEPRECATED` whereas 5.2.17 is set to `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE`).

Hope this is of use to anyone else encountering the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
Took me a time to find the solution.
The "AppKitPHPError" is pretty misleading;
the real cause is much more simple an easy to resolve.

It is simply missing credentials.
Edit the following two configs an fill in your correct DB-logon

- /whereveryouricingarootis/icinga-web/app/modules/Web/config/icinga-io.xml
- /whereveryouricingarootis/icinga-web/app/modules/Web/config/icinga-io.site.xml

After this you're done and the error will disappear

Have fun !!

ranX